# Representability of strange functor

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Consider the category Top of topological spaces. Consider the contravariant functor from Top to Set sending a topological space X to the set of all opens of X. Is this functor representable?

What if you replace "open" by "closed"?

Comment: I can't think of a nice covariant functor as you describe.  If $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous, what's the function $\mathrm{Op}(X)\to\mathrm{Op}(Y)$?  On the contrary, we do have a natural contravariant functor: the map $\mathrm{Op}(Y)\to\mathrm{Op}(X)$ takes $U$ to $f^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Of course that's the one I meant! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is (assuming the contravariant functor is what you mean, with the functoriality given by pull-back). Consider the topological space $T = \{0, 1\}$ with the open sets being $\{0\}$ and $T$. Then to give an open set in a topological space $X$ is the same as giving a map $X \to T$ (which sends said open set into ${0}$).
The case for closed sets is the same.